# VLOOKUP for an If

Tags: excel

We want to have a warning system for our server, and we want it to lookup a unique SteamID to look for any warnings that have previously been given, the spreadsheet looks similar to this:

```
PlayerName   Reason  StaffMemb  WarningNumber  SteamID
```

Like I said, I want it to search for the STEAMID in the final column and then see what the warning number is, and if another one has been given through the form, that it is to automatically add another warning to the total on WarningNumber

Comment: You cannot change the value of another cell other than the one you're putting a formula in. You'll need VBA to do something like this (a macro/script). That sounds more like a job for a database though (like MS Access).

Answer (score 1):

assuming PlayerName is in column A and SteamID is in D

assuming that warning numbers are unique and that there is just 1 SteamID per column, and that the SteamID you want to lookup is in F1 then

```
=Index(D:D,match(F1,E:E,0))
```

This will return the first Warning number.  if you want to find reason or/and player name just create another cell and change index(D:D to whatever column you want to return.

HOWEVER:

if there are multiple warning numbers per SteamID, and the only reason a SteamID is in the table is due to a warning (i.e no warning no SteamID listed in table) perhaps a count feature is better (lets you know the severity and repetitiveness of the offender)

```
=Countif(E:E,F1)
```